# Marking out points on graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

Suppose I would like to mark out and label (with their respective x, y coordinates) the maximum, minimum points of the black-lined curve, and the 2 points where p = 0.2 intersects the black-lined curve. How can I go about to do so?

```
library("ggplot2")

rho <- function(theta) {theta / (1+theta^2)}

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-6,6)), aes(x=x)) + stat_function(fun=rho2, geom="line") + ylab(expression(rho)) + xlab(expression(theta)) + 
        ggtitle("Autocorrelation at Lag 1 of MA(1)") +
        geom_hline(yintercept=0.2, color = "blue", linetype = "dashed") +
        scale_color_manual(values = c(NA, "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: What does "mark out" mean?

Comment: @OTStats Plotted as coordinate points and with the cartesian values (x, y) label.

Comment: So you just want the local min/max's _plotted_. Use of language matters :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum and minimum using the `optimize` function.

```
optimize(rho, c(-6,6))
$minimum
[1] -1.000002
$objective
[1] -0.5

optimize(rho, c(-6,6), maximum=TRUE)
$maximum
[1] 1.000002
$objective
[1] 0.5
```

You can add it to the graph using `geom_point`.

```
MIN = optimize(rho, c(-6,6))
MAX = optimize(rho, c(-6,6), maximum=TRUE)
Points = data.frame(x=c(MIN[[1]][1], MAX[[1]][1]), 
        y=c(MIN[[2]][1], MAX[[2]][1]))

P1 = ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-6,6)), aes(x=x)) + stat_function(fun=rho, geom="line") + ylab(expression(rho)) + xlab(expression(theta)) + 
        ggtitle("Autocorrelation at Lag 1 of MA(1)") +
        geom_hline(yintercept=0.2, color = "blue", linetype = "dashed") +
        scale_color_manual(values = c(NA, "red"))

P1 + geom_point(data=Points, size=2, aes(x,y) )
```

[image: Plot with max and min added]

Comment: Hi G5W, thank you for your message! I was wondering if we can mark it out and label on the graph instead.